# 文字コードUTF-8について。

Tags: java

ネットを通して文字コードについて勉強中です。
下記のコード「System.out.println(str.equals(new String(bytes, "UTF-8")));」の実行結果でtrueが返ってきますが「abc」と「97, 98, 99」が一致することを文字コード表「http://seiai.ed.jp/sys/text/java/utf8table.html」などを見て確認できません。どうやって「abc」と「97, 98, 99」が一致していることが分かるのでしょうか。

```
try {
    String str = "abc";
    byte[] bytes = { 97, 98, 99 };

    System.out.println(str.equals(new String(bytes, "UTF-16")));
    System.out.println(new String(bytes, "UTF-16"));

    System.out.println(str.equals(new String(bytes, "UTF-8")));
    System.out.println(new String(bytes, "UTF-8"));    

} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: 16進数の`61`==10進数の`97` ですが、そういう疑問でしょうか？

Comment: コード表は１６進表記になっていますのでコード表６１は１０進で９７です。 例えば、`{ 97, 98, 99 }`の代わりに `{ 0x61, 0x62, 0x63 }`のようにしてみてはどうでしょうか